# Can not ping a particular ip

Tags: networking, network-protocols

I am allocating IPs to 2 VxWorks based machines simultaneously using OpenDhcpServer, the machines send the DHCP request upon powering on. The server allocates the IPs but a am not able to ping the second machine although the ip is correctly allocated . I logged into the machine using telnet and it confirms that the ip is allocated. what could be a problem?

Comment: That might be more for serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe it's configured not to respond to ICMP ping requests. Does it time out or gets refused?